# How long does the actual screen update take on a typical monitor?

Tags: display, refresh-rate

I'm trying to better understand how a monitor's refresh cycle works. I'm not talking about GPUs or OpenGL or anything like that; I'm purely interested in the hardware side of things.

My questions are:

- How long does the actual screen update take on a typical monitor? (e.g. Supposing a 60Hz refresh rate, how much of the 16.6ms is used for drawing, and how much is the vertical blank interval?)
- When exactly is the vertical blank interrupt sent? I assume it's at the start of the vertical blank interval (i.e. after the screen has just finished drawing) but I can't find this stated explicitly anywhere. And, assuming that's the case, is there an interrupt at the end of the vblank interval?

Comment: [This blog may help to explain](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://timetoexplore.net/blog/video-timings-vga-720p-1080p&ved=2ahUKEwj0t9DrjvnkAhWR5OAKHeJIDlIQFjANegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw3JSkyZ8uwTuDBdE7wmdu5y&cshid=1569866125656)